# Selenium switching to new modal window C# example

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium

Somethign is different about my app from what I am reading on the internet. I have a web page. It is (sigh) written in IE5 compatibility mode. (Don't know if that is relevant.) There is a  on the page that runs some Javascript and a new window is displayed upon click.

I want to get to that new window. So google tells me lots of handy tricks including much great reading here. I tried the following:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<string> handles = MainWindow.WebDriver.WindowHandles;
foreach (string handle in handles)
{
     string newWindowTitle = MainWindow.WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window(handle).Title;
     if (newWindowTitle.Equals("Personalize"))
     {
          break;
     }
}
```

Here's the thing. handles only has one element in it, the main window.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I can do this?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your first line above, run the script, and wait until you see the popup. Now step through the code. Does it work? If so, the script is probably running too fast.. you need to wait for the popup to exist before proceeding. Maybe something like `while (handles.length == 1) { // do nothing }`

Comment: I did put a break point in the code. It does not work. The window is present and visible, but handles is returning count of 1 which is the main window which spawns the other window.